# How to make webpack public path work with relative sub folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I have the following webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path'),
    MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'),
    postCssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env'),
    postCssScss = require('postcss-scss'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'material': glob.sync("./src/js/**/*.js"),
        'material-light': './src/sass/material.scss'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/'),
        filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? './dist/js/[name].js' : './docs/dist/js/[name].js',
        publicPath: 'docs/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: ['/node_modules/', './dist/', '/src/css', '/docs'],
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'eslint-loader',
                        options: {
                            fix: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                exclude: ['/node_modules', './dist', '/src/js', '/docs'],
                use: [
                    MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                            publicPath: 'docs/dist/'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            syntax: postCssScss,
                            plugins: () => [
                                autoprefixer,
                                postCssPresetEnv({
                                    stage: 0
                                }),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './docs/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        watchContentBase: true,
        open: true,
    },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
            filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? './dist/css/[name].css' : './docs/dist/css/[name].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./dist/', './docs/dist']),
    ]
};
```

With the following file structure:

```
/
   /docs/
       All html files
   /src/
      /js/
          All js files
      /sass/
          All sass files
   webpack.config.js
   packages.json
```

What I'm trying to do is the following. For development I'm using the webpack dev server to serve the contents from the `/docs` directroy. However I would like the urls in the docs to be relative to the `/docs` url so that I can use the GitHub pages. Meaning in the `/docs/index.html` I would like to reference to the `material.js` file as: `./dist/js`. And for `material-light.css` as: `./dist/css`. I would like to do this because on runing production the js, css files are saved to the `docs/dist/(css/js)` directory.

But I can't get the reference right. In the config above I have `docs/dist/` for the public path but `docs/dist/js` also didn't work. The problem is relevant for both js and (s)css files.

So my question is how can I make the `publicPath` work for both webpack dev server and github pages?

Related but didn't work:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/995
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/954
- [Webpack: Issues with /src and /dist files because of the publicPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139658/webpack-issues-with-src-and-dist-files-because-of-the-publicpath)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/6cv8dd/running_webpackdevserver_in_a_sub_directory_not/
- [Webpack-dev-server in sub directory - not compiling & no hot reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069537/webpack-dev-server-in-sub-directory-not-compiling-no-hot-reloading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple problems with the config. After asking the same question on [github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1494) I ended up with the following config:

```
const
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'),
    path = require('path'),
    postCssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env'),
    postCssScss = require('postcss-scss');

const OUTPUT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'material': glob.sync("./src/js/**/*.js"),
        'material-light': './src/sass/material.scss'
    },
    output: {
        path: OUTPUT_DIR,
        filename: 'dist/js/[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: ['/node_modules/', './dist/', '/src/css', '/docs'],
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'eslint-loader',
                        options: {
                            fix: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                exclude: ['/node_modules', './dist', '/src/js', '/docs'],
                use: [
                    MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            syntax: postCssScss,
                            plugins: () => [
                                autoprefixer,
                                postCssPresetEnv({
                                    stage: 0
                                }),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        contentBase: OUTPUT_DIR,
        watchContentBase: true,
    },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.css', '.styl', '.scss'],
        alias: {
            'js': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js'),
            'css': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/css')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'dist/css/[name].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./dist/', './docs/dist']),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you ended up removing the "publicPath" option from webpack config. So it didn't have any effect on how your bundles are served?

Comment: @properchels as it is a 2 year old question I can't recall